# How could I check the number of active sqlalchemy connections in a pool at any given time?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, connection-pooling

I have a situation where sqlalchemy keeps running out of active connections from time to time due to high traffic loads, and I would like to run some tests to verify and optimize the pooling parameters per our use case. However, I cannot find a straightforward way of polling for the count of active connections.

Current setup is on the lines:

```
args = ...
mapping = {
        'pool_size': 10,
        'max_overflow': 10,
        'pool_timeout': 30,
        'pool_recycle': 1800
    }
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(*args, **mapping)
```

The max connections on the MySQL server is set to 200 and there are about 20 web servers and celery boxes total connecting to it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The default `QueuePool` has a `status` method that [returns the following](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py#L191):

```
def status(self):
        return "Pool size: %d  Connections in pool: %d "\
            "Current Overflow: %d Current Checked out "\
            "connections: %d" % (self.size(),
                                 self.checkedin(),
                                 self.overflow(),
                                 self.checkedout())
```

`Pool.checkedout()` will return the number of checked out connections.

Comment: github link is dead.

Comment: Here's a more permanent Github link to the status function: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/d5c89a541f5233baf6b6a7498746820caa7b407f/lib/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py#L193 . Note that the newest version of the function can be seen at https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py .

Comment: From the engine `engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(*args, **mapping)` -> `engine.pool.status()`