# Limiting the number of Session objects created in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to find out how we can limit the number of sessions or if there is a way to set up a maximum number of resources in SQL Alchemy session pool. I am working with a legacy codebase that initialises SessionPool as follows. I am not sure if this is important, but we use Flask in our applications.

```
  from sql import config as sqla_config

  if Session.registry.has():
    db_session = Session()

  if db_session is None:
     engine = sqla_config.get_engine("my-db", "primary", role=None)
     db_session = Session(bind=engine)

  return db_session
```

I want to limit the number of sessions that can be created. How can I do that? This is a legacy code base so I am limited in the kind of changes I can make. I am aware of [QueuedPool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775501/how-could-i-check-the-number-of-active-sqlalchemy-connections-in-a-pool-at-any-g), but I don't know how to use it in this context.

Answer (score 0):

According to [source code](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L787). You can set the following variable in flask config to achieve what you want:

```
SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE
SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT
SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE
SQLALCHEMY_MAX_OVERFLOW
```